Aristocratic Jack profiles
I wanted to call attention to a recently-downvoted user likely being related to previous ones. I don't believe the following list is exhaustive.

from months ago, no scores above zero

from two days ago, both answers deleted by mods


I think I've seen more but can't find them right now. Maybe they were already merged
and another new one
and another one
September 2024

Thank you - I was hunting them down to cross-check and merge

I wondered if this was the same person as well https://space.stackexchange.com/users/55856/average-joe

Another new account, another worthless answer https://space.stackexchange.com/users/56011/aristocratic-jack

Possible sighting? https://space.stackexchange.com/a/66923/6944
